# Scipy installation failed with error code 1

Tags: python, scipy, pip

I'm trying to install Scipy through pip.
when doing

```
pip install scipy
```

I get the error

```
 failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-c3n82mii\Scipy\
```

I got pip updated to newest version (8.1.2) and python 3.5.2. any help?

FULL ERROR:

```
 Command
 "c:\users\MYNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe
 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\MAYNA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-c3n82mii\\Scipy\\se‌​tup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
 'open', open)(file).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), file, 'exec'))"
 install --record
 C:\Users\IDANRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-76_6hqtw-record\install-record.txt
 --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in                    
 C:\Users\MYNA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-c3n82mii\Scipy\
```

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback? AFAIK every failed installation attempt prints such a line.

Comment: Command "c:\users\MYNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\MAYNA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-c3n82mii\\Scipy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\IDANRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-76_6hqtw-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MYNA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-c3n82mii\Scipy\

Comment: Please include that in your question using the code formatter, nobody can read that in a comment :(

Comment: Thanks, but not very useful at all. Thoutput does not say much about the error :(

Comment: @idik check out this blog, it's for installing 3.23, you'll need VS 2013(they say 2012 in the blog) http://www.taywils.me/2012/12/23/pythonfinance1.html and numpy 1.11 and the latest scipy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely problem is the lack of the appropriate compiler(s) on your machine and its paths - scipy uses a lot of C code for speed and pip will by default, if there isn't a wheel available for SciPy that matches your combination of python and OS, download the source and try to build it.

I have had a look at the latest release of SciPy on pipy and it is 0.18.0rc2 which doesn't have a Windows build as a wheel.

You have 2 choices:

1. Install the appropriate compilers for your version of python and OS
2. Go to Chris Gohlke's excellent unofficial windows binaries page [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) and download the installer for your version of python.